# bash piping output to file by certain time interval

Tags: bash, pipe

There is an application that infinitely outputs something to console every 30 seconds.

For example,

```
./app
# after 30 seconds
output1

# after 30 seconds
output2

# after 30 seconds
output3
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to save the output to file using piping.

How can I flush the content in the pipe every 30 seconds, so that the file content can be rewritten with the new output?

Comment: With "to the console" you probably mean STDOUT. But I do not understand what you want to do. Saving the output could be done by `tee`. Or do you want to overwrite the file for every 30 second block of output? Or do you want to use `unbuffer`?

Comment: If you have control over `app`, change it so it writes unbuffered, perhaps with an option.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to *overwrite* a file with the new output every 30 seconds?  If you *know* the pipe will reliably be updated every 30 seconds, maybe write a simple script which runs `tail -f` on standard input and reopens standard output to the same file every 30 seconds and writes out whatever standard input has received since the previous iteration.

Comment: I want the file to be overwritten by the new output (like "output1" to "output2" to "output3" as time goes). Unfortunately I have zero control over the app. I'll take a closer look at the options you mentioned. Thanks.